# ElasticSearch Throwing an "OutOfMemoryError [unable to create new native thread]"

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We just did a rolling restart of our server, but now every few hours our cluster stops responding to API calls. Instead, when we make a call, I get a response like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'
{
  "error" : "OutOfMemoryError[unable to create new native thread]",
  "status" : 500
}
```

I noticed that we can still index data fine, it seems, but cannot search or call any API functions. This seems to happen every few hours, and the most recent time it happened, there was no logs in any of the node's log files.

Our cluster is 8 nodes over 5 servers (3 servers run 2 ElasticSearch processes, 2 run 1), running RHEL6u5. We are running ElasticSearch1.3.4.

Answer (score 3):

This can be due to the OS not allowing more threads to be created.  Increasing the number of threads per process can solve the problem.  Set the `ulimit -u` value higher.

Although the above is good, an even better solution is to [configure ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html) to use a thread pool.  This is a better solution since thread creation and destruction are expensive.  In fact, some (or all?) JVMs can't cleanup terminated threads except during a full GC.